# FOSUserBundle how to add more user roles?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use symfony2 and also I integrated FOSUserBundle. But, I see that user's roles are stored in an array. I want to add more types user's roles, and for every user it will correspond only a user role type.

For example for this problem I found this solution:

1) Create a table  'user_roles', where it can be find all user role types.

2) Between 'user' tabel and 'user_roles' tabel, it will exist a relation created by the 'role' field.

How can I do that using FOSUserBundle given that the 'user' tabel from FOSUserBundle has a 'role' field that keep an array of roles types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Role management in FOSUserBundle is the same as Symfony. [You can read the documentation here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles)

You define your roles in your security.yml in a hierarchical way.